# NEProxySettings and UDP traffic

Tags: ios, networkextension

I'm new to iOS development and would like to gain some understanding about how `NEPacketTunnelProvider` handles for UDP traffic.

In my code, I've created `NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings`

```
let settings = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress: proxyHost)

let ipv4Settings = NEIPv4Settings(
    addresses: ["127.0.0.1"],
    subnetMasks: ["255.255.255.255"]
)
settings.ipv4Settings = ipv4Settings

let proxySettings = NEProxySettings()
...
settings.proxySettings = proxySettings
```

and passed it to the `setTunnelNetworkSettings` function. And I was able to start the VPN with no issues.

However, in the debug tool, I couldn't see any UDP traffic which I'm sure there should be some. The only UDP connection had no traffic constantly.
[image]

Does the `NEProxySettings` only work for TCP? What am I missing here? (I've set `protocolConfiguration?.includeAllNetworks = true` in my `NETunnelProviderManager`)